# How to prevent bouncycastle from being loaded in Wildfly?

Tags: java-8, bouncycastle, wildfly-8, java-security

When using Wildfly 8, the Bouncycastle provider seems to be loaded automatically even when no applications are loaded - found this by setting the **-Djava.security.provider** option in standalone.bat (found the line **Set BC provider property** in the server.log file). Removing BC module itself prevents Wildfly from starting (error from Weld as I remember). I don't have BC as listed provider in **java.security.policy** also.

Wildfly 9 does not seem to auto load BC, but if I hit any URL of my REST application that uses Resteasy, the BC provider properties get set (the **Set BC provider property** line). I a unable to figure out what adds the BC provider as this happens even with a simple endpoint that returns a text. Resteasy does use BC but could that be the reason? I have excluded almost all references to code in app that loads BC provider. How to exclude BouncyCastle(BC) from being loaded in Wildfly?

Thanks,

Paddy

Answer (score 1):

Resteasy module seems to be the culprit behind adding BouncyCastle as provider (it [needs BouncyCastle for SMIME encryption](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3-RC1/userguide/html/ch38.html#d0e3082)). With Wildfly 9, this subsystem does not seem to get automatically loaded (only if your application uses Resteasy) and can be excluded using the following in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

```
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jaxrs"/>
    </exclude-subsystems>
```

But in Wildfly 8, the BC provider gets added even when no app is deployed (the provider debugging can be done using the `-Djava.security.provider` option in `JAVA_OPTS`). So if you are OK with the option of changing standalone.xml, then remove the `webservices` subsystem and this problem gets resolved.

Thanks,
Paddy